# C# type assignment and method call in single statement

Tags: c#

I have this:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<XMLHERE/>"); //This returns void
```

How do I combine into one statement?

Comment: `new Action(() => { var doc = new XmlDocument(); doc.LoadXml("XML"); }).Invoke();` Almost single statement ))

Comment: Another thing `new Action<XmlDocument>((x) => x.Load("Your xml"))(new XmlDocument());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, lest you lose the reference to the document (`doc`) and therefore find it to be inaccessible.

As other answers have began filtering in to contradict my assertion, what I will say is this. Of course, *you can* create a method to do 'the dirty work' for you, but then you're not really just turning this into a one-liner, you're just disjointing the creation (and not really saving unless you need to write this in hundreds of different places).

This might not be a bad thing in many situations, but defining a class with a single extension method to facilitate this seems ridiculous. Specifying it locally, within a class where this would be extensively utilised could be a different matter.

All in all, my answer still stands fundamentally, not considering the many contrived ways you might 'get around' this.

Comment: Thanks - as I suspected. Marked this as the answer but thanks for everyone's responses. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Use static XDocument.Parse(string xml) which returns an XDocument object;

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<XMLHERE/>");
```

Comment: Good answer, if the user has the supporting .NET version (3.5 and above).

Comment: `var foo = XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<xml />")));` The overload of static member of XDocument `Load` that accepts string as a parameter expects URI

Comment: This is great but has to be from System.Xml unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

this is probably your best *(alternative to two lines)*  option...

```
public static XmlDocument MyLazyAssFunction(xml)
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    return doc;
}
```

then here is your single statment...

```
var doc = MyLazyAssFunction("<XMLHERE/>");
```

The point here being that your original two lines is a perfectly fine way of doing what you need to do.. and it is very readable as it stands too

Comment: LOL! Good name for the function, I must say! :D

By the way, you forgot **static**.

Comment: I think the 'best' option would be to write two lines, rather than create a class for this sole purpose.

Comment: This will also cause a compile-time error: you must `return doc`.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: Not sure why I missed that out. Am I that unknowingly reliant on VS prompts :S

Answer (score 1):

With just the `XmlDocument` API you can't do this in a single line and keep the `XmlDocument` reference.  However you could write a helper API

```
public static class XmlUtils {
  public static XmlDocument CreateDocument(string xml) {
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    return doc;
  }
}

var doc = XmlUtils.CreateDocument("<XMLHERE/>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. If defining the variable does not count as a statement, you can write:

```
XmlDocument doc;
(doc = new XmlDocument()).LoadXml("<XMLHERE/>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write `extension`:

```
public static XmlDocument MyLoad(this XmlDocument doc, string xml)
{
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    return doc;
}
```

Usage:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument().MyLoad(xml);
```